# bin2dec for numbers longer than 10 bits in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel with 28 position binary numbers. I need to convert them to decimal numbers, but function bin2dec don't work with numbers longer than 10 bits. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 13):

Use the following formula to mimic a [BIN2DEC function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/BIN2DEC-function-63905B57-B3A0-453D-99F4-647BB519CD6C) that coverts larger than 10 bits.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A2,LEN(A2)+1-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1),(2^(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))-1)))
```

Remember that Excel has a numerical precision of 15 digits. If you want 28 digits, format the cell as Text or preface the string of digits with a single tick (e.g. `'`) as a [PrefixCharacter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx).

[image: bin2dec_greater_than_10]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! (btw: had to replace the "," with a ";" on my system)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use the german version of Excel and thus the formula has to be changed to:`=SUMMENPRODUKT(--TEIL(A2;LÄNGE(A2)+1-ZEILE(INDIREKT("1:"&LÄNGE(A2)));1);(2^(ZEILE(INDIREKT("1:"&LÄNGE(A2)))-1)))`. Only if by chance someone also uses the German version...

Answer (score 3):

I brute forced it with the math, may be inelegant, but for a 16 bit number where leading 0's will be displayed this works and can easily be adapted to longer strings

This works well if you are working with fixed length words, like verifying values in memory, BIT registers, etc.

```
16 bit
=BIN2DEC(LEFT(R5,8))*2^8+BIN2DEC(RIGHT(R5,8))

32 bit could be 
=BIN2DEC(MID(R10,1,8))*2^24+BIN2DEC(MID(R10,9,8))*2^16+BIN2DEC(MID(R10,17,8))*2^8+BIN2DEC(MID(R10,25,8))
```

Again, this works if you have a fixed length input, leading zeros are displayed.

Comment: Thank you. It is silly that BIN2DEC does not work with anything over 10 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new spilling formulas (see [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-vs-legacy-cse-array-formulas-ca421f1b-fbb2-4c99-9924-df571bd4f1b4) and [that](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531)) to support any number up to `1.7976931348623158e+308`, limited by Excel's [15 digits of precision and largest allowed numbers via formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

Practically speaking that's:

- All integers up to `999,999,999,999,999`
- `49 bits` in any combination
- `50 bits` as long as decimal value is less than 1 quadrillion
- `1024 bits` / `309 decimal digits` as long as you only care about 15 decimal digits of precision and it's less than `1.7...e+308`

Copy this formula and replace `A2` with whatever cell you want to convert. The formula works by extracting each digit in the string with `MID`, multiplying it by the appropriate power `2^x`, then calculates the sum of all those individual numbers. `LET` is not required, but lets you substitute `A2` in just one spot instead of several.

```
=LET(number, A2, nBitBin2Dec,LAMBDA(a,SUM(MID(a,SEQUENCE(LEN(a)),1)*2^SEQUENCE(LEN(a),1,LEN(a)-1,-1))),nBitBin2Dec(number))
```

Example results:
[image: example results]

For nicer display of these numbers e.g. grouping digits into sets of ten, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/78069101/6047827.

Here are the raw numbers to make copy-paste easier. Many thanks to [Mobilefish Big number converter](https://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php) for converting the 308 digits of `="999999999999999" & CONCAT(ROUND(MAKEARRAY(293,1,LAMBDA(r,c,0)),0))` into binary for me, and similar conversions.

- `011` 
   `3`
- `1011011011011011011011011101` 
   `191,739,613`
- `11100011010111111010100100110001100111111111111111` 
   `999,999,999,999,999`
- `1000111001100111100111000010111101011110010001001101011101111001111111111000000110000011100101100011011100010000110000000101000000010111111100101010101010000100001011100100101010111011010100010010011111011101010111111110011000100001000100100100011110100000001011010010000010111100011101001011100101101001100011110000000101110000111101011100111000111100100110000101110110110000100011001100111001000101001100110000010110100101101110011000110011101010111111100111110110001011011100101100110110000100000010111001000000110100100011111001111000011101010101100010000011100101001101111000111000101110000011011111110101001100110101111011100001011100001011101010000000110110100100100010111100100110001101111001011001111110111001100100100101100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` 
   `9.99999999999999E+307` 
   or without scientific notation it is `99999999999999900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
- `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` 
   or roughly `1.7976931348623158e+308` 
   or without scientific notation it is `179769313486231580793728971405303415079934132710037826936173778980444968292764750946649017977587207096330286416692887910946555547851940402630657488671505820681908902000708383676273854845817711531764475730270069855571366959622842914819860834936475292719074168444365510704342711559699508093042880177904174497791`