# Translating string of numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, string

So basically I have 18 digit numbers in one column. This string represents role a given person has by this table:

```
100000000000000000 -> Admin

000000000010000000 -> TL

000000000100000000 -> DEV

000000010000000000 -> Viewer

000000100000000000 -> TE

000000000000100000 -> TA
```

By the lenght of the string I assume they are more roles, which arent important now, but might be later. Problem is, there can be any combination of roles for example:

```
000000010100000000 -> DEV, Viewer

000000100100000000 -> DEV, TE

100000010000100000 -> Admin, TA, Viewer
```

My task is to translate every string into roles.

Because I know which position represents which role, I can just search the string for "1's" and by the position of the "1's" add representative roles. Here is my problem, I have no idea if VB offers possibility to search string for multiple appearance of given char and save their relative positions. If it does, then it's only a matter of adding "if then" for each role. If it doesn't, I am lost just like now.

Comment: have a look at the "Left" function and see if you can't sort it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function

Comment: You can define starting point for search, so when you find first 1, you start searching again from that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to build your roles:

```
Private Sub Test()
   Dim role As String
   Dim roles As String
   Dim i As Integer

   role = "000000010100000000"

   For i = 1 To Len(role)
      If i = 1 And Mid(role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "Admin, "
      If i = 7 And Mid(role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "TE, "
      If i = 8 And Mid(role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "Viewer, "
      If i = 10 And Mid(role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "DEV, "
      If i = 11 And Mid(role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "TL, "
      If i = 13 And Mid(role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "TA, "
   Next

   MsgBox Left(roles, Len(roles) - 2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe here is a starting point:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Dict As Object: Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim str As String, Role As String
Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant

arr1 = Array(1, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13)
arr2 = Array("Admin", "TE", "Viewer", "DEV", "TL", "TA")

str = "100000010000100000"

For x = 0 To 5
    If Mid(str, arr1(x), 1) = 1 Then Dict(arr2(x)) = 1
Next

Role = Join(Dict.Keys, ", ")

End Sub
```

Don't forget to include `dict.RemoveAll` if you intend to use this in iteration.

---

And for fun an `Evaluate` option:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String, Role As String
Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant

str = "100000010000100000"

arr1 = Array("Admin", "TE", "Viewer", "DEV", "TL", "TA")
arr2 = Evaluate("IF(MID(""" & str & """,{1,7,8,10,11,13},1)=""1"",1,0)")

With Application
    Role = Join(Filter(.IfError(.Match(arr2, Array(0), 0), arr1), 1, False), ", ")
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Another code similar to those in the answers

```
Sub Test()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim r As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim roles(1 To 13) As String

    txt = "100000010000100000"
    roles(1) = "Admin"
    roles(7) = "TE"
    roles(8) = "Viewer"
    roles(10) = "DEV"
    roles(11) = "TL"
    roles(13) = "TA"

    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        If Mid(txt, i, 1) = "1" Then r = r & roles(i) & ", "
    Next

    Debug.Print Left(r, Len(r) - 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, I realized the answers are rather similar so changed up mine.

Comment: FYI, late to the party, but added an approach via a Byte array +:)

Answer (score 2):

**a) Approach via Byte array**

In addition to the valid solutions above and for the sake of the art another approach using a byte array:

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim s As String: s = "100000010000100000"
    Debug.Print s & " ~> " & getRole(s)          ' ~> Admin, Viewer, TA
End Sub
```

**Help function `getRole()`**

```
Function getRole(code As String) As String
'[0]define identifying role position in code string (e.g. "100000010000100000")
    Dim roles As Variant, b() As Byte
    roles = Array(0, "Admin", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "TE", "Viewer", 9, "DEV", "TL", 12, "TA", 14, 15, 16, 17, 18)
'[1]assign code string to byte array (generates two elements per character)
    b = code
'[2]get the "1" positions
    Dim i As Long, role As String
    For i = LBound(b) To UBound(b) - 1 Step 2   ' check the 1st element of each char pair
        If b(i) = Asc("1") Then role = role & roles(Int(i / 2) + 1) & ", "
    Next
    role = Left(role, Len(role) - 2)
'[3]return function result
    getRole = role
End Function
```

```
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Edit ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**b) Alternative via `FilterXML()` (Excel vers 13+)**

In order to complete the whole range of different approaches, I demonstrate how to use the WorksheetFunction `FilterXML()` (available in versions 13+). As there is no need to bind to a library, you may find this simple example as an alternative to dictionaries.

```
Sub ExampleCall2()
    Dim code As String: code = "100000010000100000"
    Debug.Print decode(code)
End Sub
```

**Help functions `decode()` and `XMLRole()`**

```
Function decode(code) As String
    Dim pos As Long, cnt As Long, isReady As Boolean
    ReDim tmp(1 To Len(code))
    Do While Not isReady
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, code, "1")
        If pos = 0 Then
            isReady = True
        Else
            cnt = cnt + 1: tmp(cnt) = XMLRole(pos)
        End If
    Loop
    ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To cnt)
    decode = Join(tmp, ", ")
End Function

Function XMLRole(code) As String
    Const wellformed As String = "<roles><r t='Admin'>1</r><r t='TE'>7</r><r t='Viewer'>8</r><r t='DEV'>10</r><r t='TL'>11</r><r t='TA'>13</r></roles>"
    XMLRole = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(wellformed, "//r[.=" & code & "]/@t")
End Function
```

**Short hints to XPath**

XPath strings (here: `"//r[.=" & code & "]/@t"`) allow to search node or attribute contents enriched by conditions (here e.g.: `[.=11]` pointing to a numeric content of e.g. 11) within a wellformed node structure (comparable to html). Further sub nodes or attributes  are added by `/` to the whole term (here: attribute content of `/@t` (symbolising *type*, e.g. `'TL'`) after a `r` role node; btw the double `//r` indicates a *role* search of any `r` anywhere after the root element (here: `roles`).

Comment: Cool idea! + from me =)

Comment: Don't know, would be worth a test. Love all solutions shown here as they demonstrate that many roads are leading to Rome. Btw, each solution has its tricky merits  :-)

Comment: Added another approach via `FilterXML()` in addition to all valid solutions above :-)

Answer (score 2):

Is there a necessity to do it within VBA ?

Here's a (silly?) way to pull it off just in a sheet:

Start with your values in column A.
Across the columns, put your values for the individual roles ..

Here's how I set it up on my end (you can always hide rows/columns you don't need)

[image]

The formulas in each cell are as follows:

**D4:** (copied down to D6)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A4,LEN(A4)+1-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A4))),1),(2^(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A4)))-1)))
```

**E2:** (copied across to J2)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(E1,LEN(E1)+1-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(E1))),1),(2^(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(E1)))-1)))
```

E4: (copied throughout down to J6).

```
=BITAND($D4,E$2)
```

Obviously you can combine those to eliminate extra steps (I left them in for clarity).

The funky:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A4,LEN(A4)+1-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A4))),1),(2^(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A4)))-1)))
```

is just a tricky way of doing : BIN2DEC() on a larger value .. 
as per this thread:

[bin2dec for numbers longer than 10 bits in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693029/bin2dec-for-numbers-longer-than-10-bits-in-excel)

once you have them in decimal form, shoving them through BITAND makes it easy :)

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help my final code looks like this:

```
Dim Role As String
Dim roles As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim b As Integer
b = 1
    For Each c In Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows
        Role = c.Value
        For i = 1 To Len(Role)
            If i = 1 And Mid(Role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "Admin, "
            If i = 7 And Mid(Role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "TE, "
            If i = 8 And Mid(Role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "Viewer, "
            If i = 10 And Mid(Role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "DEV, "
            If i = 11 And Mid(Role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "TL, "
            If i = 13 And Mid(Role, i, 1) = "1" Then roles = roles & "TA, "
        Next
        Range("B" & b) = Left(roles, Len(roles) - 2)
        roles = ""
        b = b + 1
    Next c
```

I had a bit of problem with cycling through each cell, but that's just due to my little knowledge of AVB. It's not the prettiest code but it serves it's purpose, thanks again for helping me out :)